# custom find_module always called with 'fullname' equal to None

Tags: python, import

Im trying to implement custom `find_module` and `load_module` methods.
It seems to be called, but the `find_module` is always called with 
both fullname and path always set to `None`.
I don't understand why.

Here is the program stub:

```
class TouchImportLoader:
    def load_module(self, fullname):
        return None

class TouchImportFinder:
    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        #fullname and path seem to be None always, when printed here
        return TouchImportLoader()

sys.meta_path.append(TouchImportFinder)
```

---

I'm calling it with simple scripts such as:

```
import time
print(time.clock())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path):

> The `find_module()` method is called at least with the absolute name of the module being imported. If the module to be imported is contained in package then the parent package’s `__path__` attribute is passed in as a second argument.

The `path` argument is only passed for packages.

In your example, you should get a `TypeError`:

> unbound method `find_module()` must be called with `TouchImportFinder` instance as first argument (got `str` instance instead)

...since you are adding the finder *class* to `meta_path`, not an *instance* of the class:

```
sys.meta_path.append(TouchImportFinder)
```

This should read:

```
sys.meta_path.append(TouchImportFinder())
```

Comment: Thank you. Im embedding Python into another application, and could not catch any error returns early in its initialization.  This fixes the problem.